# Removing unused styles when using tailwind with react vite app

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, purge

I am trying to remove the unused css during build process.
npm run build => "build": "tsc && vite build --base=/root/",

I am getting error message like below cannot read property 'match' of undefined
[image]

Tailwind config entry:

purge: [{ enabled: true, content: ['./src/**/*.tsx'] }],

Answer (score 2):

Try use this config,

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    safeList: [],
    content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.tsx', './src/**/*.ts'],
  },
```